# List of appointed offices in the US at the state level

Tags: united-states, republic

Where can I find a list of political offices in the US, held at the state level, that are appointed rather than elected?

Comment: This will be an exceedingly long list.  As a comparison, there are over 8800 Schedule C appointments in the federal government. While I can't say multiply that by 50, you will have redundancies.

Comment: @AffableGeek A few examples would do. I don't need an exhaustive list.

Comment: @Web_Designer do you have a specific state in mind?  This will certainly very from state to state.

Answer (score 3):

It would probably vary wildly by state. I did find this [list for Texas](http://governor.state.tx.us/appointments/positions/). The State Controllers Office notes that the govenor will [appoint about 3,000 positions](http://governor.state.tx.us/appointments/). In California, they have a [list of Appointed State Officials](http://www.calhr.ca.gov/state-hr-professionals/Pages/appointed-state-officials.aspx) that have salaries set by statute, but I couldn't find a complete listing.